# How to write MS Unit Test for the code having console.writeline

Tags: c#, mstest

I'm using bubble sort for sort a array in descending order and print the output in console.writeline method, now i'm confused how to write a unit test to test against the console.writeline

```cs
//Console Application Code
public int PrintData(int[] input, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] <= 0)
        {
            status = -2;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (input[i] < input[j])
                {
                    int temp = input[i];
                    input[i] = input[j];
                    input[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input[i]); //How to check this output in MSTest
    }
}

//MS Test Code
[TestMethod]        
public void ArrayDisplayingInDescendingOrder()
{
    int[] arr = new int[5] { 3, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
    int[] expected = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };            
    array.PrintData(arr, 5); 
    //What i should do here          
}
```

Comment: You don't write an unit test for what is printed to the console, you write a unit test for what is resulted from your sorting function. The printing should be separate from the sorting function itself (yo could for example have another function which saves the result of the sort function to a variable, and then loop over that to print). At that point, you can write a unit test that enters your unsorted array into your sorting function, and then see if the result of that matches a sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to test the `Concole.WriteLine` calls I would create a class with an interface to encapsulate the `Console.WriteLine`. Could look like this.

```
public class ConsoleService : IConsoleService
{
    public void WriteToConsole(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this service in your PrintData method and mock the calls in your test and verify the calls; for example with Moq.

Easier would be to return a List from PrintData and add each entry to the list instead of `Console.WriteLine(input[i]);` because then you can test if the correct values where added. And in your application you simply can print all entries with a for each loop.

So you have to change your code to make it testable. But your code would be cleaner after this (I would hardly recommend not to use any UI interaction in logic classes). Good example on how tests can make code cleaner, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `TextWriter` argument to your method and use this one to write:

```
public int PrintData(int[] input, int n, TextWriter sw)
{
    ...
    sw.WriteLine(input[i]);
}
```

When you call the method, you could then supply any `TextWriter`, including `Console.Out` or a stub:

```
PrintData(new int[0], 0, Console.Out); //writes to the console

//in unit test:
TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
PrintData(new int[0], 0, tw); //writes to tw
Assert.AreEqual("...", tw.ToString());
```